# A word for ''Try to solve some difficult problem once more''

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

Is there in english a word connotating the idea ''try to tackle a difficult problem once more''? The word I want has meaning more than simply ''try again''.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Some context would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about a single word, but some phrases you could use:

> Make another attempt.
>   Work harder to solve ...

Informally:

> Take another stab at it.
>   Give it another go.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest the phrase "to reengage the problem."

Answer (score 1):

How about *persevere*:

> to continue doing something or trying to do something even though it is difficult ([Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persevere))

Note that *persevere* can also be used for continuous successful (but difficult) action, rather than just repeated unsuccessful attempts, but I would say it definitely meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've just heard this expression at BBC Radio 4:

- [To have a second bite at the cherry](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/another-a-second-bite-at-of-the-cherry)

To emphasize the hardness of the task, one may add an adjective before *cherry*, such as *tough, hard*.

> Let's have a second bite at this tough cherry.

Or, to substitue the word *cherry* with something a bit tougher. Say, borrow from the idiom '[a hard nut to crack](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hard_nut_to_crack)'.

> Let's have a second bite at this hard nut, hope it will crack this time.

P.S. Personally I like Obfuskater's *reengage*: the word has military connotations ("engage the enemy") and thus seems to imply hardness.

Answer (score 0):

In English, we have a prefix to describe a verb as being **retried**

**Retry** is the word you are looking for

Other examples of using this prefix:

- Re-learn
- Re-send
- Re-run (as in televison, or running cables)
- Re-live